# Running some code every day at certain times

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I am currently developing a windows service in C# which is supposed to run a data import every day at configurable times. For this purpose I have created a class "ExecutionTime" which contains the attributes "Hour" and "Minute" to specify a time when the data import should be executed. When the service is started, the configured times are parsed into one ExecutionTime object each and those objects are then added to a list "executionTimes". I also created a class "Scheduler" which is responsible for checking if the data import should be executed and executing it once one of the configured times is reached.

I have already created a possible solution but I am not sure if my solution is considered "good practice" or if there are any edge cases when my code will not work the way it should. Could I therefore please get some feedback on my idea? Is it good? Can it still be improved?

My idea is to run the following code inside a while-loop:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

foreach (ExecutionTime executionTime in executionTimes)
{
    if (now.Hour == executionTime.Hour && now.Minute == executionTime.Minute
        && (lastExecutionTime.Hour < executionTime.Hour || lastExecutionTime.Minute < executionTime.Minute || lastExecutionTime < DateTime.Today))
    {
        PerformImport();
        lastExecutionTime = now;
    }
}

Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

Please do not suggest using scheduled tasks as a solution because that is not up for discussion, I have to implement this in a windows service.

I have already asked this question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58541127/how-to-run-some-code-at-certain-times-every-day) but someone recommended to ask it here instead.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. How many `ExecutionTime` objects will be in `executionTimes`?

Comment: @Heslacher Thank you! Currently there will be four objects in it. There is a possibility that more will be added in the future but I doubt it.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/ it can be adjusted to your needs. Running inside a service won't be a problem either. If you click on the right side on "Documentation" you will see a "Getting Started" as well.

Comment: @Heslacher Thank you for the idea! However, I'd like to avoid including yet another whole library into my project just to run my code at a few given times per day. I know that it is usually not a good idea to re-invent the wheel but this problem seemed simple enough to me that I can do it myself in a few lines of code. Could I please get some feedback regarding the code that I provided?

Comment: It can start as a very simple task and evolve just so little that it can get messy to deal with while extending it. I definitely agree that you should use a well tested and a stable/reliable library if you can. Apart from **Quartz.Net** you can also take a look at https://www.hangfire.io.